# Iterating through rows does not respect sorted order

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to iterate through all rows in a sheet, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the iterator to respect the sorted order of the worksheet. I have a worksheet that I am sorting all rows/columns by a single columns value, but when iterating through, it still uses the original index order.

Ex Sorted Row Order:
1,2,4,5,3

Iterator goes through original numeric order:
1,2,3,4,5

```
Sub Iter()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    RowCount = 0
    Dim OldRowValue As Integer
    Dim AppendCount As Integer
    Dim DivValue As Integer
    Dim NewRowValue As Integer
    OldRowValue = -1
    AppendCount = 1
    DivValue = 0

    Worksheets("OrdersSoln").Activate
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    
    'This line does nothing other than sort the already sorted worksheet
    Range("A1", Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address).Sort Key1:=[AB2], Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    
    For Each rw In sh.Rows
        If RowCount = 1 Then
            OldRowValue = NewRowValue
        End If
        If RowCount <> 0 Then
            'Exit when no more data
            If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 28).Value = "" Then
                Exit For
            End If
            
            'Set new row value
            NewRowValue = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 28).Value
            'Debug.Print NewRowValue
            If NewRowValue = OldRowValue Then
                'Set new cell value with same AppendCount
                sh.Cells(rw.Row, 29).Value = "FTW_" & AppendCount
            Else
                'NewRowValue is different, increase AppendCount
                AppendCount = AppendCount + 1
                
                'Is new row value a new day?
                If NewRowValue \ 100 > DivValue Then
                    DivValue = NewRowValue \ 100
                    'SetAppendCount back to 1
                    AppendCount = 1
                End If
                sh.Cells(rw.Row, 29).Value = "FTW_" & AppendCount
            End If
            
            OldRowValue = NewRowValue
            
        End If
        RowCount = RowCount + 1
    Next rw
    
    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

The rest of the code seems to be working fine, I literally just need it to use the sorted order of the cells and not the original order.

If there is no way to do this, I'm sure I can just get the unique values of the column as a list and then order it and iterate through that, setting cell values accordingly or something.

2D Examples:
Unsorted Data:

| Row # | Column of Interest |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 3 | 110 |
| 4 | 100 |
| 5 | 100 |

Sorted Data:

| Row # | Column of Interest |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 4 | 100 |
| 5 | 100 |
| 3 | 110 |

In the for loop, it uses the unsorted order, whereas I expect the sorted order.

Comment: Aren't you looking at the sorted column? AB  = 28 ?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes I am, but the For loop does not use the sorted order, as "sort" seems to be a display only property. Sorting does not actually re-arrange the row indexes, so when you iterate through 1->100 rows, you get the unsorted order.

Comment: I've never seen sorting not influence a loop order - it's definitely not "display only".  There is some other issue you're not seeing.  FYI in the examples you give it's not clear which is "expected" and which is "observed"

Comment: Sorted Order: 1,2,4,5,3  
Expected Loop Order: 1,2,4,5,3  
Actual Loop Order: 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: If you're sorting on that column why do you expect an unsorted order?  Why is "Sorted order" not 1,2,3,4,5 ?

Comment: OK I cant type in these comments, let me edit the main thing with a 2D example

Comment: If you `Debug.Print rw.Row` are you not seeing 1,2,3,4,5 ?